# Como criptografar dados no App.config

Tags: c#, xml, criptografia, app.config

Gostaria de criptografar as keys (ApiKey e Secret) abaixo no App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="ApiKey" value="sggrtdsfg"/>
   <add key="Secret" value="524524524"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Já procurei em vários posts, alguns fazem por linha de comando usando "aspnet_regiis", mas no meu caso tem que ser via código mesmo.

Criei um console application, assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CryptoTrader
{
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        CriptografarAppConfig();
      }

      static void CriptografarAppConfig()
      {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection section = config.AppSettings;

        if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
           section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider");
           section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
           config.Save();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Quando o programa roda, não ocorre nada simplismente! O App.config continua com os dados sem estarem criptografados, por que isso ocorre?

**Resolução:**
O código acima funciona! O problema era que o App.config da solution não era atualizado, mas sim o CryptoTrader.exe.Config dentro da pasta CryptoTrader\bin\Debug e CryptoTrader\bin\Release

**Fonte:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840904/app-config-are-not-saving-the-values

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pesquisei o App.Config (ou Web.Config) não permite persistir alterações em tempo de execução e tudo fica em memória, ou seja quando o aplicativo é reiniciado as alterações são perdidas.

Como referência encontrei a resposta no Stack em Inglês https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value

No caso como sugestão criptografe os dados e em tempo de execução recupere as informações.

Se você tem necessidade de fazer deploys ou algo específico possa usar uma abordagem de gerar o arquivo por um terceiro e altera-lo via esse outro software.
Neste caso use a leitura de arquivos xml para fazer as modificações necessárias

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme! Já atualizei a resolução acima.